# Moments of a SDE: a detail on the information set

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, geometric-brownian, expected-value

Very basic questions. Let $(z_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a standard Brownian motion and let
$$dS_t = \mu S_t dt + \sigma S_t dz_t.$$
When we write $E\left( S_t \right)$, do we mean $E\left( S_t \big| F_0 \right)$? The hesitation stems from my habit with discrete time processes which, in levels, would not be covariance stationary.

Comment: You’d typically start with $\mathcal F_0=\{\emptyset,\Omega\}$ which means you have no information at all. Only constant functions would be measurable, suggesting that we know today’s value, $S_0$. Every integrable random variable is independent of this trivial sigma algebra, i.e. conditioning on it does not refine the standard expectation.

Comment: @Kevin Thanks for the precision. That's what I was suspecting.